# Autoincrement does not increment sequentially if last row was deleted

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains an auto incremented primary key id. If I delete the last row (highest id, for example id = 22) and insert a new row, the new id starts at 23. What should I do to start it with 22 again?

Example Table:

```
              PrimaryKeyID             Column 2             Column 3
Row             1 (auto-incr.)             x                    x
                2                          x                    x  
deleted row     3                          x                    x
inserted row    4 (should be 3)            x                    x
```

Comment: Why do you need to start with 22? A sequence has no meaning, it's just a series of number might have gaps, who cares.

Comment: No, MySQL will not reuse old ids (apart from the recalculation of "next id" for innodb tables after a restart...). You should not rely on sequential ids, but IF you really need this for some reason, handle the "next id" manually, instead of autoincrement.

Comment: dont delete the row.

Comment: its example if I have only two rows and I have deleted second one and if I create new one its automatically starts with 3 not 2 and I

Comment: yes. it does. dont delete the rows if you dont want that to happen. or use a trigger to simulate auto_increment, but sets the value to max(id) + 1

Comment: what happens if you delete a row from the middle of the table? ie `PrimaryKeyID = 1` in your example. Do you expect it to fill the gap or continue on from the end of the sequence?

Comment: @pala_ yes i expected it should fill

Comment: just dont delete the rows then. flag them as deleted with another column, and check for that in your queries. there's no point to gap filling

Comment: Since there exists no case where someone **needs** sequential numbers, the easiest way out of this situation is that you accept the fact that you won't get sequential numbers from `auto_increment`. I realize this isn't the comment or answer you want, but `auto_increment` **does not provide sequential numbers**, it just provides next *higher* number in order to quickly give a unique number, and it does so taking concurrency in mind. Basically, force it to go sequential and you'll have so many problems within minutes. Or you can just forget about sequential numbers and live a nice life.

Comment: @N.B. pala_ but how I can make crud operations like in my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879161/how-to-get-id-of-selected-table-item-in-php?noredirect=1#comment47882996_29879161

Comment: Question - why do you need sequential numbers and gap filling? Is there an actual, technical reason for that or is it just bothering you in terms of OCD?

Comment: @Sultan your CRUD operations don't care if the the numbers are perfectly sequential, and if they do, you are doing it _completely wrong_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from `MYSQL` developer comment. See More https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

> In order to reset the auto_increment, in a situation where some of the
>   most recently added rows were deleted, use:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=1234  //this is a demo number
```

Then future insertions will be numbered from 1234 again (unless you still had rows numbered greater than 1234, and then the future insertions will start from the greatest number + 1 ).

Comment: yes i reset it with Truncate table but should I in every operation make it

Answer (score 1):

Execute a query to check that your auto_increment (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema='database' AND table_name='table') is larger than max(audited_id) and perform a fake insert. You can put that logic with --init-file or on a trigger, please refer this article.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#c12158