# How to get id of selected table item in php

Tags: php, mysql

I should get `id` from a table to make a request. But I did it in this way.

My table :
id(AI);name(Varchar);authir(varchar);category(varchar);

I think if there any solutions to make that thank you my problem appears in this lines:

```
Print  "<td><a href='editt.php?id=$id'>edit</a> </td>";
Print  "<td>  <a href='delete.php?id=$id'>delete</a> </td>";
```

Full code:

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Book name</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th><th>
                <th><th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php 

    $id = 0;
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
        $id++;
        Print "<tr>";
        Print" <td>".$info['name']."</td>";
        Print "<td>".$info['author']."</td>";
        Print  "<td>".$info['category']."</td>";
        Print  "<td>  <a href='editt.php?id=$id'>edit</a> </td>";
        Print  "<td>  <a href='delete.php?id=$id'>delete</a> </td>";
        Print " </tr>";

    } 

?>
```

I wondered if there are some other ways to make redirect with current id of selected row id=$id
Can you look photo there if pointer in edit or delete link link id is =2 but actually in db it is 3

Comment: Don't you have an `id` column that you can use via `$info['id']`?

Comment: @kingkero        Print  "<td>  <a href='editt.php?id=  "$info['id']"  '>edit</a> </td>";
not working

Comment: That's generating a syntax error I'd guess. You need to concatenate the variable in there.

Comment: @chris85 I am newbie in php          Print  "<td>  <a href='editt.php?id=  . "$info['id'] "  '>edit</a> </td>";

Comment: And that gives no output? Do you have a column named `id`? Can you post your table structure? Please edit your question to add the additional information.

Comment: please stop using deprecated `mysql_` connections

Comment: @nomistic what should I use because I am newbie please can you tell me

Comment: @chris85 i have edited can you look please

Comment: Either `mysqli_`or `PDO`.  Both are not hard to learn, especially for a new user (no more difficult than the old way, and much more secure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can show the table structure and full php code we can help more, but just for now it seems you should just:

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    Print "<tr>";
    Print" <td>".$info['name']."</td>";
    Print "<td>".$info['author']."</td>";
    Print  "<td>".$info['category']."</td>";
    Print  "<td>  <a href='editt.php?id=".$info['id']."'>edit</a> </td>";
    Print  "<td>  <a href='delete.php?id=".$info['id']."'>delete</a> </td>";
    Print " </tr>";
}
```

And stop using `mysql_*` functions, It is deprecated. You should use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @Sultan and? my code doesn't work? where do you initialize your `$data` variable? where is your query string? my code must work for you.

Comment: $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books")  or die(mysql_error());  
 in the begining where I connect to db

Comment: should I make crud operations like this

Comment: or there exist other ways with MVC and so on

Comment: There are many many different ways to get the same result in php. I have no idea what do you mean when `crud operations`. If you need proper way you can google there are lot of examples how to create or use different mvc frameworks with database. But at the moment from the code you provided I've assume that you don't understand the MVC concept yet. so try just to understand the concept first, and transform your code into MVC.

Comment: thank you yes I am newbie in php can you recomend some books tutorials you have read thank you